# Using SED to match emails in a sql dump and replace them

Tags: sql, regex, sed, grep

I am trying to scrub the emails from a SQL dump file, and I could use some advice.  I am doing this because I want to send some developers "mostly correct" information, without sharing actual user information.  I have a BASH script that loops through line-by-line, so I am trying to do a SED replace on the INSERT statements.  I need to iterate through the dumb because I have some other scrubbing stuff, which is working.  I have some regex that works (I think), but I cannot seem to get it into SED. The regex of:

```
'(.*@.*?)'
```

Will match 'emailname@emaildomain.com', but I'm having trouble getting it into SED, and I'm sure that there is a better REGEX.  Here's my example line.

```
'firstname','emailname@emaildomain.com','lastname'
```

I hope to be able to replace whenever I have an @ between quotes with 'empty@invalid'.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually this statement `I have a BASH script that loops..` means you've gone off the rails somewhere. If you post some sample input and expected output we could help you do it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed "s/'[^@']*@[^@']*'/'empty@invalid'/g"
```

I've replaced your `.*` with the more specific `[*@']*`, which only matches strings which *don't* have any single-quotes `'` or `@`, which is needed because `sed` is *greedy*.

Comment: **Edit:** Typo: change "more specific `[*@']*`" to "more specific `[^@']*`".